# Adding fonts to a flutter app in production

Tags: flutter, pdf, fonts

I have a flutter app, the include more than 100 fonts, but when I was trying to add Chinese, Korean, and Japanese Noto font to the app, for each language the font size is almost 30MB, so it's not practical to add the fonts unless the user is pressing on the font and wants to use it.

So, is it possible to download the font in production without installing it before publishing?

I can't use google fonts package because I am using flutter pdf package, and the package requests the font to be installed before and can't work with google fonts package to bring the font immediately in production.